# Error with avro schema: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' Avro Schema

Tags: python, json, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-kafka-python

An error occurs while processing the schema, I can not understand what the problem is. Where am I making a mistake?

I have this schema:

```
my_schema =
"""
    {
        "name": "MyClass",
        "type": "record",
        "namespace": "test.namespace",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "int"
            },
            {
                "name": "data",
                "type": {
                    "name": "data",
                    "type": "record",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "name": "detail",
                            "type": {
                                "name": "detail",
                                "type": "record",
                                "fields": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "obj_id",
                                        "type": "int"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "system_id",
                                        "type": "int"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "email",
                            "type": [
                                "string",
                                "null"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "phone",
                            "type": [
                                "string",
                                "null"
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "params",
                            "type": {
                                "type": "map",
                                "values": "string"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
"""
```

This is the data I am using in this scheme::

```
value = {
        "id": 7,
        "data": {
            "detail": {
                "obj_id": 1,
                "system_id": 1
            },
            "email": "test1@example.com",
            "phone": None,
            "params": {}
        }
    }
```

Then I initialize AvroProducer:

```
value_schema = avro.loads(my_schema)
producer = AvroProducer(kafka_config, default_value_schema=value_schema)
producer.produce(topic=topic, value=value)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
File "/home/Project/test.py", line 108, in produce
    producer.produce(topic=topic, value=value)
  File "/home/Project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/confluent_kafka/avro/__init__.py", line 99, in produce
    value = self._serializer.encode_record_with_schema(topic, value_schema, value)
  File "/home/Project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/confluent_kafka/avro/serializer/message_serializer.py", line 108, in encode_record_with_schema
    schema_id = self.registry_client.register(subject, schema)
  File "/home/Project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/confluent_kafka/avro/cached_schema_registry_client.py", line 209, in register
    schema_id = schemas_to_id.get(avro_schema, None)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: I think the `default_value_schema` is supposed to be the string form of the schema (and it looks like your code is do a `loads` to turn it into a dictionary). What about trying `default_value_schema=my_schema`?

Comment: @Scott  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_json'` or if i use my_scheme dictionary instead of string`TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` again